# Assigning a CSS Variable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to cause a specific .div to change background colors when clicked on.
As the user will be able to change their colors, the color must be a variable and should be ran when .ready().

I am using a CSS variable '--main-color' as the variable I would like to change the background color to, however I cannot seem to find a jQuery way of solving it while using '$(this)'.

Is there a specific way to apply a custom CSS property/variable with a .click() function?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 // CREATE GRID
 for (i = 0; i<1152; i++) {
  var board = document.createElement('div');
  board.className = 'grid';
  board.addId = 'color'
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(board);
 };
 // END CREATE GRID

   // HOVER AND CLICK FUNCTION //
       $('#color-picker').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
    var choice = ev.color.toHex();
        document.body.style.setProperty('--main-color', choice);
 });

   $('.grid').hover(function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
         $(this).css('background-color', 'var(--main-color)');
  });
 });
 // END HOVER AND CLICK FUNCTION


});
```

```css
body {
 background-color: #222;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family:'Patua One', cursive;
 color: #FFF;
 --main-color: #000;
}
*{
 background-color: #222;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family:'Patua One', cursive;
 color: #FFF;
}

#title {
 font-family:'Revalia', cursive;
 font-size: 3em;
 color: #FFF;
 text-align: center;
}

.menu {
 float:left;
    clear: left;
    width: 300px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left:5%;
}

#container {
 height: 800px;
 width: 800px;
 border: 1px solid #424242;
 margin-left: 30%;
 margin-top: 5%;
 background-color: #FFF;
}

.grid {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 border: 1px dotted #424242;
 background-color: #FFF;
 display: inline-grid;
}

div.grid:hover{;
 background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.active {
 background-color: var(--main-color);
}

.form-control {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 34px;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #222; 
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #F85658;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
    -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,-webkit-box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    -o-transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
    transition: border-color ease-in-out .15s,box-shadow ease-in-out .15s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Sketch</title>

  <!--Javascript & jQuery Imports /-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src='js/main.js'></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!--CSS Imports /-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link href="CSS/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--Font Imports /-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patua+One|Revalia" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--BOOTSTRAP IMPORTS /-->
  <script src='js/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.js'></script>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css'></link>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='CSS/bootstrap-colorpicker.min.css.map'></link>

 </head>
 <body>
 <div id = 'title'>
 ZACH<span style='color: #F85658'>'</span>S PIXELMAKER</div>
 </div>

 <div class = 'menu'>
  <div class = 'color-section'>
  <p class="ui-corner-all" style="padding:12px;"> Color:
  </p>
  </div>
  <div id="color-picker" class="input-group colorpicker-component">
    <input type="text" value="#000000" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
    <script>

    </script>
</div>

 </div>

 <div id = 'container'>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "I am trying to cause a specific .div to change background colors when clicked on." Well then use the right tool for the job: look at the complications this is instead of a simple jquery .click() or .mousedown() and .css()

Comment: Just store the color's hex code in a JS variable called TheColor and write .css('background', TheColor) where needed

Comment: @frenchie Thanks. your solution worked perfectly. I tend to forget the KISS solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the color to a class, and toggle the class.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click',function() {
  this.classList.toggle('color');
})
```

```css
body {
  --main-color: #000;
}
.color {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

Or using jquery...

```js
$(function() {
  $('div').on('click',function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('color');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  --main-color: #000;
}
.color {
  background-color: var(--main-color);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>div</div>
```

Comment: The issue with toggling a class is that once the color of the class changes, all div's in that class will also change colors. I would like to keep them their originally assigned color when first clicked on.

Comment: @ZMonk Sorry, I don't understand and your demo doesn't work. *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve]."*

Comment: I am using an offline plugin and can't find a CDN. To clarify: I have tried the toggleClass solution. The problem is that if I reassign the background-color in the .color class, then all div's in that class will update their colors to the new assigned background color. Think of a box with 4 squares. If I assign the top two to Green, then change the variable to a new color, those top two will change colors instead of staying green because I reassigned the class' color.